Response to Preflight request does not pass Access Control Check:No Access Control Allow Orig header is present on the requested header
I am getting this error when calling .net core 6 API from Ajax and passing Authorization in header. Configuration in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddCors(options=\> { options.AddPolicy("Name mentioned here \*\*\*\*", policy=\> { string\[\] domains=settingsOptions.CorsOrigins.Split(';'); policy.WithOrigins(domains) .AllowAnyHeader() .AllowAnyMethod() .AllowCredentials() .WithExposedHeaders("IS-TOKEN-EXPIRED", "IS-COOKIE-EXPIRED"); }); });

app.UseHttpsRedirection(); app.UseStatusCodePages(); app.UseStaticFiles(); app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(); app.UseRouting(); app.UseCors("Name mentioned here \*\*\*\*"); app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization(); app.MapControllers(); app.Run();

Also I have added this in webconfig as well:
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Api-Key, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />

AJAX CODE:
    type: 'GET',
                url: "
https://*URL*/home/GetRefType"
,
                
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("ABT"));
                },

On LocalHost everything working but when I deploy on server it starts throwing error.

I suggest you could enable the FRT tracing inside the IIS to further troubleshooting, looks like this is block by other IIS module. More details about how to use FRT to capture the logs,you could refer to this article.

@BrandoZhang ..when I dig more I see when I am using http on localhost its working but whem I am using https in api and mvc project its throwing same error ..

How about you disable the cors chekcing inside your project to see if this will work or not.

@BrandoZhang when we remove cors policy that time also its not working and giving me same error.

OK do you have other authentication inside this project like windows auth?

@BrandoZhang yes forms authentication os there in web application.also I see my api creating cors issue when request coming from https but working fine when its coming from http.

Do you have any reverse proxy setting inside the IIS? Besides, I still suggest you capture an FRT logs to see which part return the cors error.

@BrandoZhang..I have enabled IIS CORS module and did setting in web.config and this resolved this issue..but now I m facing authorization issue with message token invalid signature was not found.  Do you think I need to publish another post on stackovetflow of you cam help me here itself?

Please post it at another post .
